# Bundling and Minification not rendering correct path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I'm having an issue with the bundling and minification feature of ASP.NET MVC 4 Basically I have the following bundle setup:

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/backendcss").Include(
                    "~/backendContent/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                    "~/backendContent/assets/jui/css/jquery-ui.css",
                    "~/backendContent/assets/jui/jquery-ui.custom.css",
                    "~/backendContent/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css",
                    "~/backendContent/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css",
                    "~/backendContent/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css",
                    "~/backendContent/assets/css/fonts/icomoon/style.css",
                    "~/backendContent/assets/css/main-style.css",
                    "~/backendContent/plugins/pnotify/jquery.pnotify.css",
                    "~/backendContent/plugins/msgbox/jquery.msgbox.css",
                    "~/backendContent/IntroJS/css/introjs.css"));
```

when they are placed on the page they come out like so:

```
<link href="/backendContent/assets/jui/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/backendContent/assets/jui/jquery-ui.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/backendContent/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/backendContent/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/backendContent/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/backendContent/assets/css/fonts/icomoon/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/backendContent/assets/css/main-style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/backendContent/plugins/pnotify/jquery.pnotify.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/backendContent/plugins/msgbox/jquery.msgbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/backendContent/IntroJS/css/introjs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

1. First problem is that the Tilda `~` is not coming in the beginning of the link and I think that's one of the problems (site not rendering properly) now all of the above css stylesheets are resolving but there are a lot of imports and relative urls (images) and I think those are getting messed up (without the bundles, if I just point to `~/backendContent/....` everything is working just fine
2. Second problem is that when I set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` there are a lot more problems and digging deeper I get a huge list of 
   (4368,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@import'
   (4368,9): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found 'url("layout.css")'

I don't know if this is important but the minified and rendered style link produced by `@Styles.Render("~/backendcss")` is:

```
 <link href="/backendcss?v=eMX6YcVB78xPWZV9Dw6seHqsT742J8_M1irfUC0IdaQ1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Any Ideas? I'm sorry but this is the first time I'm using this feature and with this site having so many css and js it would save a lot of bandwidth and speed up the whole site. Plus its just plain cool (that is if I can get it to work)!!!

Comment: Cross check order of css file. and also remove .min files or rename it. Than check without using BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; that every file is coming or not? Let me know the error if occurred again.

Comment: @kunjee ok so after a bunch of debugging and going back and fort in the source, I found out that without the `EnableOptimizations = true` the bootstrap file was missing. after fixing the `.min` the site renders fine. When I turn on the optimizations however, I get all those error `CSS1019` still

Comment: I'm gonna try to split all the folders into separate bundles but doesn't that kinda defeat the purpose of bundling?

Comment: yes, it do... But to find a root cause it is the only way... after finding the issue combine it again. Trust me it is not because of bundling. I have done bundling for more than enough files for very big project and it works like charm.

Comment: if you able to find out file please update the question so it will help to solve the issue behind this error. As far as I can see there must be some error in css which is not allowing it to bundle. So, when optimization is false it just serve without checking but otherwise it throws error while trying to bundle. Even you can check output log to find out file.

Comment: Ok, I will do it today and report back.

Comment: Ok so when I extracted the CSS file with all the imports and almost everything,is fine now except some of the images are not shoing up, ill dig some more and report back

Answer (score 1):

1. The `~` is not supposed to be rendered. That's a special character in asp.net which means `the root of the application`
2. I'm not sure why you are having issues with the actual minification, but that'd be pretty hard to diagnose without the source.
3. The link when optimized should look like that. the ?v=xxx at the end is for cache busting so that people get the updated css when you change the css files.

Answer (score 1):

Darren Kopp is right "The ~ is not supposed to be rendered. That's a special character in asp.net which means the root of the application"..

And don't use ".min" because when you set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` it will be minimize your files.. So it should be like this;

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/backendcss").Include(
                    "~/backendContent/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css",
                    "~/backendContent/assets/jui/css/jquery-ui.css",
                    "~/backendContent/assets/jui/jquery-ui.custom.css",
                    "~/backendContent/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css",
                    "~/backendContent/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css",
                    "~/backendContent/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css",
                    "~/backendContent/assets/css/fonts/icomoon/style.css",
                    "~/backendContent/assets/css/main-style.css",
                    "~/backendContent/plugins/pnotify/jquery.pnotify.css",
                    "~/backendContent/plugins/msgbox/jquery.msgbox.css",
                    "~/backendContent/IntroJS/css/introjs.css"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think for minification to work you need to add  in global.asax file

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

Also can you try to create different groups of for example keeping jqueryui separate from bootstrap and so on.